# Is this accepted as an example using session?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session

**Update to my Question ..**

**the best way to achieve acceptable security is to use ASP.NET Web Site Administration Tool**
the following is only a demo to use session but it is **NOT RECOMMENDED** for professional use.

Please follow the advice of **PhillFox** to achieve better results

**Login.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Login.aspx.vb" Inherits="Login" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

</div>
UserName<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
Password<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Login" />
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
    DataFile="~/App_Data/pr.mdb" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [username], [role] FROM [users] WHERE (([username] = ?) AND ([password] = ?))">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" Name="username" PropertyName="Text" 
            Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox2" Name="password" PropertyName="Text" 
            Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:AccessDataSource>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Login.aspx.vb**

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Partial Class Login
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page


Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)     Handles Button1.Click

    Dim mygr As New GridView
    mygr.DataSource = AccessDataSource1
    mygr.DataBind()
    Me.form1.Controls.Add(mygr)

    If mygr.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Session("username") = TextBox1.Text
        Session("role") = mygr.Rows(0).Cells(1).Text.ToString
        Response.Redirect("default.aspx")
    Else
        Response.Redirect("login.aspx")
    End If
End Sub


End Class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They best way to handle security for you site is to use .Net's built in Forms Authentication. You can learn more by reviewing this walk through on the MSDN site: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879kf95c(VS.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879kf95c%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Once you set up the Membership provider detailed in the link above, you can use the built in LoginControls, or use the existing controls you've detailed in your question; but I'd recommend going with what .Net provides, all the features you need are already included.

Comment: Dear PhillFox, this will result in an SQL express database containing roles and users. what i need is the same but with Microsoft Access NOT SQL database.

Comment: Right, it is possible to use Access instead of SQL Express. Here is an article that explains how to use Access as a database for storing your membership information: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/010307-1.aspx.

Comment: At the very least, you should consider using FormsAuthentication to protect your site and add the FormsAuthenticaion.RedirectFromLogin method on your code above (instead of the Response.Redirect("default.aspx")). You can find out more about that method here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka5ffkce.aspx

Answer (score 1):

i agree with phillfox
the .Net membership of course is much superior than your solution, however if you decide to use an access database in your backend keep in mind that:

-you cant use LINQ to SQL with access backend

-max 2GB

-max 256 concurrent connection